# Inaccurate WMI data

Tags: c#, wmi

I'm trying to get the total VRAM of a system using WMI calls, I'm testing in my dev machine which has a NVIDIA GTX 1080 8GB GPU but the property `AdapterRAM` from `Win32_VideoController` says that my card only has 4 GB of VRAM. Not sure if there's any issue with the property or my code.

Here's the code I'm using

```
private void GetVideoInfo()
{
    foreach (var mgmtObj in GetManagementClassProperties("Win32_VideoController"))
    {
         VideoInfoLabel.Content = ToUInt64(mgmtObj["AdapterRAM"]) / 1073741824;
    }
}

public ManagementObjectCollection GetManagementClassProperties(string id)
{
    return new ManagementClass(id).GetInstances();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This could be the usual WMI vs Hardware issue - as the docs for Win32_VideoController say _"Hardware that is not compatible with Windows Display Driver Model (WDDM) returns inaccurate property values for instances of this class."_